# Office Client opens all files in read only if sharepoint is open via https

Tags: 2016, office, https, read-only

Since today all MS Office files (Word, Excel) are open in the word Client application as **Read Only** mode, if I visit the SharePoint via https. If I Change the URL to http instead the Office files can be edit in word/Excel.

The HTTPS certificate is self signed but the certficated is added to the trusted certifcate store.

Any ideas why this happend? I think it is related to [this Office security patch](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/4462138/description-of-the-security-update-for-office-2013-february-12-2019),
because there is this Paragraph in the description: *"This security update resolves a security feature bypass vulnerability that exists when Microsoft Office does not validate URLs"*

Comment: can you check this certificate if is not expired?

Comment: The certificate valid until 2028

Comment: so try uninstall this security patch on any laptop and try if its surely caused by this patch, if yes, we will dig more

Comment: even if there are other updates from the feburar update - this one is not included. within the updates released on 5.3 i don't find any update that would point to my problem in its description.

Answer (score 0):

i set up a lot of tests and noticed that the problem on my laptop was only related to my profile. so other users logon on my laptop and everything worked. so i finally removed my whole windows / AD profile from my computer - after that it works. i don't know why this problem has arisen and there are other users besides me where i have to use this procedure but at least it leads to success in the end